# Windows application 'A' replacing and then running application 'B'

Tags: windows, vb6, installation, release, patch

I am about to release a new version of a Windows application that includes a boodle of files that swells the size of the package and slows down the install.  A follow on release is also in the works, but won't need to change any of the files in the boodle.  So, I could make that release a patch for the folks who already have the software... just install a new executable.

My idea on this is to have the first release install a small stub executable like normal.  When run, the stub would run the full size executable that was installed in the users area, like \users\public\my_app\run_me.exe

But when the stub is run, it would first check for the existence of a newer version to run, say \users\public\my_app\new_me.exe

If new_me.exe exists, the stub would rename run_me.exe for backup and then rename new_me.exe to be the current executable to run.  Then the new version is executed.

The goal here is to make upgrades a lot easier for the user.  My software can check for new versions and download it for the user (if she wants it).

Are there risks here?  Is there a more standard way to accomplish this?  Is there some sample code available that has been in production?

I do development with VB6 and the software runs on XP and newer.

Thanks -  John

Comment: You could even have the main application check for a new version and offer the user a choice to update now or not.  Then you could spawn your updater to download the new version, run a cleanup script for the old version, and install the new version (with elevation if required, for example if you install into Program Files).  It is easier if you are using reg-free COM activation in your packaged application, but if you install into Program Files anyway that's more or less a moot point.

Comment: Thanks Bob. My worry is that someone's security settings wouldn't allow a Program Files executable to run another program in the user's area.  But it sounds like you don't see any issues either?

Comment: Wouldn't the program already be running in the user's context anyway?  It should have access to anything the user has access to. A secondary updater program would probably need to be run with elevation so after that it almost has access to anything.  If these programs are not installed but plopped somewhere within the user's profile I don't see the issue aside from being sure to avoid registering components in the virtualstore.  We are probably straying beyond the sort of thing this site is for though, discussions don't work here.

Comment: My initial tests show things working fine on my machines, so I'm going to build the support into the application.  If it doesn't work for somebody, they will just need to install a new version.  Thanks again, Bob!!